# .animate not working for multiple objects

Tags: jquery, object, animation, jquery-animate

I have a Question concerning the .animate class of jQuery.
Is there no possibility to animate multiple objects of the same class?
Somehow it just won't work.

Here is an idea of how it is at the moment

```
<div class="demo">
    <div id="box1">hello</div>
    <div id="box2">bye</div>
</div>
```

and the javascript

```
function mySquare(name){

        this.animateMe = function(){
            $box = $("#" + name);

            function there(){
                $box.animate(
                {left: 450 }, 2000, function (){
                    //alert($box);
                    back();
                }
                );
            }

            function back(){
                $box.animate({left: 0 }, 2000, function (){
                    there();
                }
                );
            }

            there($box);
        };


    }

    var square1 = new mySquare("box1");
    square1.animateMe();

    var square2 = new mySquare("box2");
    square2.animateMe();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9ccuxyhw/

after the first animation there, only the second div keeps on animating and theres a lag
Why does the first div stop animation?

Than you for your help

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$box = $("#" + name);
```

to

```
var $box = $("#" + name);
```

And it will work.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9ccuxyhw/1/